# Permanent redirect from one domain to another but same host

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I had domain name which expired today and I have registered new domain with same name but different extension. New domain is in the same host where was old domain... just from `http://example.com` become `http://example.net`

Now I have added in `.htaccess` this which I took from another question here on SO but when I go to old domain doesn't redirect me. Is this is because they are on the same hosting account?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.net [R=301,L]
```

New domain is working without any problems and is loading correctly if I go directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't own example.com, you have no control over where it is hosted now.  Read up on how DNS works https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System

Comment: Yes, since yesterday I don't own it anymore. No one is owning it yet since it is just expired.

Comment: Try this at the command prompt: `nslookup example.com` or better yet do `nslookup` first, then `set type=any` and then `example.com`

Comment: `** server can't find example.com: NXDOMAIN`

Comment: Exactly, there is no DNS record for it because nobody owns it.

Comment: Yes, thats why I can't make common redirect and don't know how to make it :)

Comment: Wait did you mean that is not possible at all?

Comment: You need to own the domain to be able to set the DNS record that translates example.com to the IP address of your web server. Can't do it captain.